# JS filter array if includes string in array

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter out each in an `array` if the `value` of `category` is of a user selected `value`.

For example, I have an `array` of `exampleData`

```
[
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "377856cd-9477-58a4-9596-888ebc8c03d5",
        "title": "Tubing & Sledding",
        "category": [
          "Winter"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "a7370249-af7a-538a-aaae-91f308575bb8",
        "title": "Snowmobiling",
        "category": [
          "Summer",
          "Winter"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "4136389a-77b7-5e07-8c95-1c856983d27b",
        "title": "Snowshoeing",
        "category": [
          "Winter"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "79fc5efa-e1a4-5e65-94cd-97a5245ed0af",
        "title": "X-Country Skiing",
        "category": [
          "Winter"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

And I would like to `filter` the array to only `return` the `objects` with `Summer` included in the `category` field `array` .

To do this, I have tried

```
const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(({ node: category }) => {
  activity.category.includes('Summer');
});
```

Yet, `console.log(exampleCategory)` shows with zero results.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the boolean result of calling `.includes`:

```
const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(({ node: { category }}) => {
   return category.includes('Summer');
});
```

Also, you can directly do that without return

```
const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(({ node: { category }}) => category.includes('Summer'));
```

Example

```js
const exampleData = [{    "node": {      "id": "377856cd-9477-58a4-9596-888ebc8c03d5",      "title": "Tubing & Sledding",      "category": [        "Winter"      ]    }  },  {    "node": {      "id": "a7370249-af7a-538a-aaae-91f308575bb8",      "title": "Snowmobiling",      "category": [        "Summer",        "Winter"      ]    }  },  {    "node": {      "id": "4136389a-77b7-5e07-8c95-1c856983d27b",      "title": "Snowshoeing",      "category": [        "Winter"      ]    }  },  {    "node": {      "id": "79fc5efa-e1a4-5e65-94cd-97a5245ed0af",      "title": "X-Country Skiing",      "category": [        "Winter"      ]    }  }];
const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(({ node: { category }}) => category.includes('Summer'));

console.log(exampleCategory);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I feel stupid. Cannot believe that I missed that. Will accept as correct answer as it allows. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes

- You are returning `undefined` from callback passed to filter. You need to explicitly return the result of `includes` or use Arrow Function to implicitly return the result.
- You are using `includes()` on wrong value.`activity` will be `undefined`. Simply check for `element.node.category.includes`

```js
const exampleData = [ { "node": { "id": "377856cd-9477-58a4-9596-888ebc8c03d5", "title": "Tubing & Sledding", "category": [ "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "a7370249-af7a-538a-aaae-91f308575bb8", "title": "Snowmobiling", "category": [ "Summer", "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "4136389a-77b7-5e07-8c95-1c856983d27b", "title": "Snowshoeing", "category": [ "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "79fc5efa-e1a4-5e65-94cd-97a5245ed0af", "title": "X-Country Skiing", "category": [ "Winter" ] } } ]

const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(x => x.node.category.includes('Summer'))

console.log(exampleCategory)
```

You can also use Object Destructuring.

```js
const exampleData = [ { "node": { "id": "377856cd-9477-58a4-9596-888ebc8c03d5", "title": "Tubing & Sledding", "category": [ "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "a7370249-af7a-538a-aaae-91f308575bb8", "title": "Snowmobiling", "category": [ "Summer", "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "4136389a-77b7-5e07-8c95-1c856983d27b", "title": "Snowshoeing", "category": [ "Winter" ] } }, { "node": { "id": "79fc5efa-e1a4-5e65-94cd-97a5245ed0af", "title": "X-Country Skiing", "category": [ "Winter" ] } } ]

const exampleCategory = exampleData.filter(({node:{category}}) => category.includes('Summer'))

console.log(exampleCategory)
```